# I want to go to last record of access database without using ID

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been trying to find this. I am using access 2010 and I have some data in a few tables and I want to select the last row from each one and add them to a new database. All the databases have random ID so I can't use the Sort by ID function.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you wanting to do this in Access itself, or using SQL/VBA? If it's the first, your question should go on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), as it's a general software question. If it's actually a SQL or VBA question, please edit your question to include what you've tried so far that isn't working for you. Also, if there are "random ID" values, how do you decide which is the "last record"?

Comment: Databases don't (and shouldn't) guarantee any "order" of records unless they are specifically identified in the table.  You've already stated that ID is random, thus "last row" is meaningless without specifying what field determines the order.  If by "last row" you mean "latest row," then you need to add a timestamp column and populate it every time a record is added.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is small, you can pass it to a datatable in the frontend and use something like this,

```
lastRow = datatable.rows(datatable.rows.count-1)
```

Else, You can add a 'created_datetime' field in database which holds the inserted datetime and retrieve its maximum date since your ID field has random number...

Answer (score 0):

open vba (alt + F11)

```
dim rst as recordset
set rst = docmd.runsql (sql statement here) e.g. (select * from tablename)
rst.movelast
```

you've gotten to your last record in vba

you can add it to a new table database by using an insert statement.

Comment: The poster indicates specifically that there's no way to order the data, so what would your `SELECT` use to decide which is the "last record"? SQL doesn't guarantee any order without using an `ORDER BY` clause.